# Got this error in app.js trying to run this code again but getting the same error help me guys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import ComponentsScreen "./src/screens/ComponentsScreen";

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Components: ComponentsScreen,
 },
 {
  initialRouteName: 'Components',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
   title: 'App'
  } 
 }
);

  export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

[Got this error when i try to run the code in mobile using expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fut3Q.jpg)

got this error in app.js file when running in mobile help me

Comment: If my answer is right, please answer it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `from` on the fourth line.

Change:

```js
import ComponentsScreen "./src/screens/ComponentsScreen";
```

To:

```js
import ComponentsScreen from "./src/screens/ComponentsScreen";
```